# How to save two type of data in one field in codeigniter?

Tags: html, forms, codeigniter, input

I'm using codeigniter.
I Have a form. And there have some checkbox.
But how to save to save double data in one field?

Here is my code:

**In View/form.php**

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="members" name="data" value="members">
    <label for="members"> Members</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="client1" name="data" value="client1">
    <label for="client1">Client1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="client2" name="data" value="client2">
    <label for="client2">Client2</label><br>
```

**In controllers:**

```
$this->input->post('data');
```

But how to input double data from controller?
Please someone help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question. You wanted to save checkboxes value in one database field.

Get checkbox values in array and then convert to string while storing.

Html -

```
<input type="checkbox" id="members" name="data[]" value="members">
<input type="checkbox" id="members" name="data[]" value="members1">
<input type="checkbox" id="members" name="data[]" value="members2">
```

Controller -

```
$member = $this->input->post('data');
$member = implode(','$member);
```

So if user checked `member and member2`. Then this will store `member, member2`.

And while extracting it convert string to array -

```
explode(','$member);
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.